# What does while(($#)); do ...; shift; done mean in bash, and why would someone use it?

Tags: bash, parameters, while-loop

I came across the following while loop in a bash script tutorial online:

```
while(($#)) ; do
   #...
   shift
done
```

I don't understand the use of the positional parameter cardinality in the while loop. I know what the `shift` command does, but does the while statement have some special use in conjunction with `shift`?

Comment: I suspect the part of the body you elided is also calling shift, at least conditionally, so that the number of arguments consumed each time through the loop may vary.

Comment: BTW, it's better form to have a space after the `while`.

Comment: @chepner - no it does not.

Comment: BTW, `(( $# ))` isn't anything specific to `while` -- you can use that anywhere (in an `if`, on its own and checking `$?` after, in a `(( $# )) || exit`-style compound command, etc). If you're asking more about what `(( $# ))` means than about `while` specifically, that might be called out.

Answer (score 5):

Every time you do `shift`, the number of positional parameters is reduced by one:

```
$ set -- 1 2 3
$ echo $#
3
$ shift
$ echo $#
2
```

So this loop is executed until every positional parameter has been processed; `(($#))` is true if there is at least one positional parameter.

A use case for doing this is (complex) option parsing where you might have options with an argument (think `command -f filename`): the argument to the option would be processed and removed with an additional `shift`.

For examples of complex option parsing, see [BashFAQ/035](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) and [ComplexOptionParsing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ComplexOptionParsing). The last example of the second link, [Rearranging arguments](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ComplexOptionParsing#Rearranging_arguments), uses the exact `while (($#))` technique.

Comment: Agreed. I don't think the use `while` with `$#` is very readable.

Comment: There's a compelling use case for it, but that case is when you need to sometimes consume more than one parameter at a time, like `--arg argvar`; in that case, there'll be an additional `shift` in the handler for `--arg`, so `argvar` doesn't get separately processed again on its own.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ah, for complex option parsing, right? I'll mention that.

Comment: Exactly so. If you wanted to, you might add a link to [BashFAQ #35](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035), which showcases such a practice.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy On it :)

Answer (score 5):

Let's have a script `shi.sh`:

```
while(($#)) ; do
    echo "The 1st arg is: ==$1=="
    shift
done
```

run it with:

```
bash shi.sh 1 2 3  #or chmod 755 shi.sh ; ./shi.sh 1 2 3
```

you will get

```
The 1st arg is: ==1==
The 1st arg is: ==2==
The 1st arg is: ==3==
```

Note the: **1st** (and the usage of `$1`).

Comment: Might add the missing space -- granted, current versions of bash aren't calling it a syntax error, but that doesn't make it good form.